# It is show the name of the class when I use a template in a combobox

Tags: wpf

I want to update the text of an item in a combobox when the item is saved.

Although the entity that I use as source implements the notify property changed event, it is not update. I have read the solution it is to use a data templeate instead of DisplayMemberPath.

So I am using this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TipoComponenteTemplate"
          DataType="{x:Type clases:TiposComponentesUI}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TipoComponente}"/>
</DataTemplate>


        <ComboBox Name="cmbTiposComponentes" Width="150"
                  Text="{Binding TiposComponentesTexto, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TiposComponentes}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TipoComponenteTemplate}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding TiposComponentesSelectedItem}">
```

That works partially, in the way when I open the combobox, the items show the correct text, but when I select one of them, in the textbox of the combobox it is shown the name of the class instead of the data in the property TipoComponente that is defined in the data template.

So I would like to know how I could show the same text in the textbox than the text that is shown in the items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced this scenario and both the the `ItemTemplate` and the `DisplayMemberPath` solutions work fine for me, as long as the `ComboBox`'s  `IsEditable` property is set to `False`.

**When `IsEditable="False"`**

Here's what I have:

Book.cs

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp2;
public partial class Book : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string? _author;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string? _title;
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp2;

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; } = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Book? _selectedBook;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Books.Add(new Book { Author = "Jim Weasley", Title = "The mystery of eggplants" });
        Books.Add(new Book { Author = "Ryan Reynolds", Title = "Doplhins and how to beat them" });
        Books.Add(new Book { Author = "Sarah O'Connel", Title = "What is djent?" });
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void UpdateRandomBookTitles()
    {
        foreach (var book in Books)
        {
            book.Title = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BookDisplayTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Book}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding UpdateRandomBookTitlesCommand}" Content="Randomize book titles" />
        <ComboBox
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookDisplayTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook}" />

        <!-- This will work as well -->
        <!-- <ComboBox
            DisplayMemberPath="Title"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook}" />-->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

After you've selected a book, changing it's `Title` will be reflected in `ComboBox`'s `Text` as well.

**The problem: when `IsEditable="True"`**

Once you set `IsEditable="True"`, this stops working and I believe it's intentional. When `IsEditable="True"`, the `ComboBox`'s `Text` is only update when:

- an item is selected
- user types text manually

Changing the `SelectedBook`'s `Title` does nothing here, my guess is so that it doesn't overwrite user input. Only selected another item will do that.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I would need the combobox is editable, but it is interestenting to know that is because of this.